# Can't run AVD in Android Studio, Android home issue Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, emulation, android-virtual-device

> PANIC: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_S_API_24], use -list-avds to see valid
>   list. ANDROID_SDK_HOME is defined but could not find
>   Nexus_S_API_24.ini file in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd (Note: avd
>   is searched in the order of
>   $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and
>   $HOME/.android/avd)

This is the error I get, I have set the Android Home variables like this in the bashrc:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/myname/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/home/myname/.android/avd
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/myname/Android/Sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because of AVD name. try below command to get AVD information to fix this issue.

```
~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager list avd
```

run above command in your terminal and note the Android Virtual Devices name from response.

to run AVD

```
~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator @xxxxxxxx
```

Note: xxxxxx replace with your avd name.

Comment: when I run "android list avd" I get an empty list, I have created a few virtual devices with Android studio and I can see them on .android/avd

Comment: @JoseGonzalez what was you solution? can you please mention it here

Comment: I ended up using my phone